# Custom Site template not available in office 365

Tags: office-365, site-template

In office 365 i created a site template using [this](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/11/23/how-to-save-site-as-template-in-sharepoint-2013/). The template is available in solution gallery and is activated.But when creating a new subsite, In the template selection I cannot find the custom tab with the new template created. When I try to create the subsite using sharepoint designer I can see the template. How an I make the custom template available in the site , so that I can create a subsite using the custom site template using the site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Site Settings` -> `Page Layouts and Site Templates` (in `Look and Feel` Section) and check if your custom template is selected there.

Comment: You are a genius :)

Comment: Glad to help. If this works please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are having issues with the custom tab not showing up when you want to apply a custom template to a site collection. Make sure that the setup language of the site collection is the same as the language from where you made the template. It took me over 12 hours to finally figure this out.

Wanna save you the trouble!

Comment: This is the issue I had in SharePoint online. Had to use the same language for the subsite as the site collection was created with...

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but you need to download the site template as a solution file and then re-upload it to the solution gallery every time you create a new site.

Here is the full answer:

[Create site collection using custom site template SharePoint Online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160174/create-site-collection-using-custom-site-template-sharepoint-online)