# Create site collection using custom site template SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom, site-template

Can we create a SharePoint site collection using custom site template from admin center in SharePoint Online? I do not see any option to upload the solution where we can uplooad the custom template to be used.

Answer (score 4):

it is little tricky,here are the steps.

1. simply proceed as you would normally to create a new Site Collection, however when it comes time to select a template to base the new site collection select the Custom tab (on the extreme right), which should only have one option – **< Select template later … >.**
2. Select this option and continue with the new site collection creation process.
3. Now navigate to the new site collection URL. You will see the **Solution Gallery** heading.
4. Click on the Solution Gallery, it will empty( for first time).
5. Now you need to upload your Custom Site template.
6. After Uploading, please make sure it is Activated if not click on the Activate button.
7. Once **activated** close the dialog and Now You will this **template** under **Custom Tab**
8. Select the Custom Site Template and Click **Ok**

Ref: http://blog.ciaops.com/2013/07/using-site-template-with-new-site.html

Comment: I want to automate this using SharePoint Online Management Shell.Is it possible to do it that way